# Installing Sip api on a tablet that does not currently support it?

Tags: android, api, voip, sip

I'm writing an application that uses the android sip api to place sip calls but the tablets that my company ordered do not support the native api.  Is there any way/hack that I can install the native api on a device that doesn't currently support it?  Or what is the best way to approach this?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way/hack that I can install the native api on a device that doesn't currently support it?

Only by finding some alternative firmware that supports your tablet and offers SIP support, and loading that firmware onto the tablets.

Comment: Alright that's what I thought, I was hoping that I could force something.  Thanks

Comment: There are third-party SIP apps that AFAIK do not use the native SIP API. Some are open source. You could always investigate them and see if they will prove suitable.